# What hardware would be suitable for a relatively 'future-proof' consumer VR desktop gaming system?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, desktop, gaming

I'm considering building a new PC. I'm not going to jump into this generation of consumer VR hardware, but the next set might have me.

Can I build something now, or in the next few months if it's worth waiting for a particular hardware release, that should see me through the next few years of consumer VR advancement?

Comment: We cannot predict what will be needed in the future.  This type of question isn't on topic on any SE website currently.

Comment: We can't know, but we can predict. For example, the performance numbers reported with Pascal, against previous graphics rendering and hardware improvement patterns over time, current VR system requirements, rumoured next generation VR hardware, and the differences in between, could give a good idea of how long the latest generation of graphics cards might last. I was hoping someone might have done this research

Comment: The current hardware on the market can barely handle today VR Systems, there is no possible way, to predict what the next generation VR systems will require from PC hardware.  This type of questions are just going to draw low quality opinions, like the current answer.

Answer (score 0):

- i5 CPU (or i7, but i5 is enough). Get skylake if you can, but haswell is fine too, if you can save a few bucks. Hyper threading mostly helps with very CPU intensive game (Think cities skylines here), I don't know of a single VR game that falls into this category, so no, you don't need it.
- Definitely get one of the newest graphics cards (That means GTX 1070 or 1080 from Nvidia or waiting for the AMD cards that will be released). This is by far the most important thing.

Also check out reddit.com/r/buildapc

Comment: Which generation of i5 and i7? Is HT any use for VR?

Comment: There isn't that much difference between the generations. Skylake if you can afford it, but Haswell would also be fine. If HT is of use depends on the game, but for 90% of games it won't help.

Comment: Also go with something with DDR4 Memory. As this is the next generation of Desktop memory.

Comment: If he is indeed going for skylake, that is. Using DDR4 on haswell won't end well.